# How to incorporate feedback from pull request

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am new to bitbucket. I tried to google it but unable to find exact answer for my question.

I created a feature branch. Made few changes in the feature branch then I pushed/committed all the changes from my local machine to Bitbucket feature branch on bitbucket.org. Then I created a pull request and added a reviewer.

My senior reviewed the pull request and added his code reviews/comments in the pull request.

Now I am stuck at this point how to incorporate changes which are mentioned by the pull request reviewer. Should I create another branch? I am totally stuck what to do next.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The pull request is from your feature branch (the version on Bitbucket) into some other branch. The most common workflow here is to make the changes on your local feature branch, commit those, and push those commits to Bitbucket. That would cause the pull request to reflect those changes and give the reviewer an opportunity to review them. Depending on team norms and how people have notifications set up, you may also want to leave a comment in the pull request to let reviewers know about the changes.

Answer (score 0):

The next step would be to [merge](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/merge-a-pull-request-808488562.html) the accepted pull request into your desired target branch. By accepted I mean, that all changes necessary for the pull request to be deemed complete have to be part of your current branch. In case you only performed a local review of the pull request, you should [push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36251332/how-to-push-to-a-specific-branch-on-bitbucket-using-git) the changes on your current branch to your Bitbucket Server.